# Show that subtraction of matrices is neither commutative nor associative. Please review my work.

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, noncommutative-algebra, associativity

> Show that subtraction of matrices is neither commutative nor associative.

**My Work**

Let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times n$ matrices with elements $a_{ij}$ and $b_{i j}$, respectively.

Commutativity says that $A + B = B + A$.

$A - B = a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}$

$B - A = b_{i,j} - a_{i,j}$

Since subtraction of numbers is not commutative, we have that $a_{i,j} - b_{i,j} \not= b_{i,j} - a_{i,j}$.

$\therefore A - B \not= B - A$.

Let $A, B, $ and $C$ be $m \times n$ matrices with elements $a_{ij}$, $b_{i j}$, and $c_{i,j}$ respectively.

$(A - B) - C = (a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}) - c_{i,j}$

$A - (B - C) = a_{i,j} - (b_{i,j} - c_{i,j}) = a_{i,j} - b_{i,j} + c_{i,j} = (a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}) + c_{i,j} \not= (a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}) - c_{i,j}$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work for correctness and provide feedback.

Comment: Why don't you just find (counter)example?

Comment: @JohnWatson I could, but that, in my eyes, would be taking taking the easy way out.

Comment: Taking the easy way out is a very good idea in mathematics, when it is possible. If there's an easy way out why not take it? Your proof is correct, but it can be made a lot simpler: consider the case $m=n=1$. $5-2\neq2-5$, thus the statement is false. If you want more generality then $a-b\neq b-a$ but I don't see the point

Comment: For non-zero $A,B, C,$ $$A-B\neq B-A$$ and $$A-(B-C)\neq (A-B)-C.$$

Comment: @JohnWatson Because the problem is from a rigorous textbook on linear algebra, and none of the provided proofs are proof by contradiction. I wanted to write a solution that maintained the style of the author.

Comment: @ThePointer: Your motivations are good, but a proof in this instance would involve specific numbers and does not represent an easier way.

Comment: Providing a counter-example is **not** a proof by contradiction. As the statements you are trying to prove are not false in general, demonstrating the existence of a counter-example is the only rigorous approach that is gong to work: trying to show that the statements are always false must fail. The constructive way of demonstrating the existence of a counter-example if to give an explicit counter-example.

Comment: @RobArthan  Oops, you’re right. I misspoke. And you’re right about the 0s; I should have stated that the matrices are nonzero.

Comment: @RobArthan If I had stated that the matrices are nonzero, then would my proof be correct?

Comment: I'd say no, because $1-1=1-1$ is still true

Comment: @user2723984 You’re right. I should have used a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is incorrect for when the matrices are all 0. A counterexample is the way to show what you want to show. The reason is that if you want to show $\forall x \in X P(x)$ is false, you must show, $\exists$ $x\in X$ such that $-P(x)$ is true